# How to execute code from character with R?

Tags: r

I want to execute a code on R that has been stored as a character.

For example, imagine I have this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot <- "ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length))+geom_histogram()"
```

I know that the correct way is to store this:

```
plot <- ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length))+geom_histogram()
```

whitout quotes, but this is not what I have, so..

How can I adress to plot the chart I want if I have the code with quotes? How can I plot

```
  plot <- "ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length))+geom_histogram()"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `eval(parse(text = plot))`